# How do you apply two separate orders of rotation on geometry node instances?

Tags: animation, node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry

I am trying to make a field of grass "blow in the wind."  I have used random rotations to vary my grass clumps, but can't figure out a way to apply and set the rotation values so I can add another layer of animated rotations using an animated noise.  Currently when I apply the animated rotation vectors with Rotate Instances, the instances carry the random rotation and bends every which way instead of all-together in a direction.  Is there a way to "zero out" the instances after they've been rotated randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are searching for?

you can uncheck "local space" on rotate instances and plug in the position to give each a global angle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting, using the position input as the pivot point AND turning off Local Space.  These field nodes are taking some time to get used to.